# What is the right way to access activity context from the ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

This is not a question to solve an error, I just want to make sure I am going for the right approach and not introducing any memory leaks and all.
I'm using DataBinding with ViewModel the view model holds the data of the specific view and also do all type of view listeners (eg: onClick) inside the view model like this

```
// a view model to control the app drawer

    internal class DrawerModel : ViewModel() {
        // view automatically updates when I change the values of the following
        var userName: String = "Login"
        var userEmail: String = "For better experience"
        
       // automatically calls this function when the user presses the logout button in the view

        fun onLogOut() {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        }
    }
```

And sometimes I need a reference to the Activity context so that I can update other views from inside the view model but I heard the view model should never hold a reference to the activity instance because it introduces memory leaks, so I did it in the following way to prevent that

I added my activity as a variable in the  field in the XML file with the view model

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name="drawer"
            type="com.ci.evangelian.base_page.PgModels.DrawerModel" /> // the view model class
        <variable
            name="baseActivity"
            type="com.ci.evangelian.base_page.BaseActivity" /> // activity that needed for refenece in the view model
    </data>
```

and in the click of my button, I bound the ViewModel like this

```
          <Button
            android:onClick="@{()->drawer.onLogout(baseActivity)}" // this method will be automatically called when the button is pressed
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/bt_logot" />
```

the updated code for onLogout() that accepts an activity param is below

```
internal class DrawerModel : ViewModel() {
        var userName: String = "Login"
        var userEmail: String = "For better experience"
        // code changed here added baseActivity as parameter
        fun onLogOut(baseActivity: BaseActivity) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        }
```

and initialized my binding class and attached it to the view model and the activity like this

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    internal lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding // this is the binding for the view in the XML

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        // binds the view with the binding
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_home)

        val model: PgModels.DrawerModel = PgModels.DrawerModel()

        // connects the view model with the binding
        binding. drawer = model

        // connects this activity to the binding so that it will pass the instance of this 
        // class to the method onlogout() in DrawerModel
        binding.baseActivity = this

    }
}
```

I did it like this due to the logic that the view model won't save any instance of the activity hence no memory leak but can access all other variables and methods inside the activity, binding is the one who holds the instance of the activity as well as the ViewModel instance, I expect it won't introduce any memory leaks,
I'm not sure if I'm doing right or not, If it is not the right way please suggest a better way to get a similar output.
binding is the one who holds the

Comment: `AndroidViewModel` allow you to access the application context, but I doubt that is what you want. And `ViewModel` should not interacting with the view,, you can use `LiveData` or `StateFlow` for it.

Comment: But AndroidViewModel only give application context right? How can I get Activity context from it?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, use `LiveData` or `StateFlow` to interact with the activity.